# Java/Swing FEST test fails absurdly

Tags: java, swing

I have a test that sometimes fails on the `requireSelected()` call, and I can't figure out why.

```
public void testSimple() {
  JRadioButtonFixture fixture = getFixture();
  fixture.check();
  fixture.requireSelected().requireVisible();
}
```

I tried changing the code to run on the EDT instead of in the test's main, but none of the fixture's methods are allowed to be invoked from the EDT it seems.

Why does this test fail?

Update: More details:

There isn't anything in the `setUp()`.

Here's the failure trace:

```
Java.lang.AssertionError: [javax.swing.JRadioButton[name='button', text='text', selected=false, enabled=true, visible=true, showing=true] - property:'selected'] expected:<true> but was:<false>
at org.fest.assertions.Fail.fail(Fail.java:87)
at org.fest.assertions.Fail.failIfNotEqual(Fail.java:60)
at org.fest.assertions.BooleanAssert.isEqualTo(BooleanAssert.java:129)
at org.fest.swing.driver.AbstractButtonDriver.assertThatButtonIsSelected(AbstractButtonDriver.java:142)
at org.fest.swing.driver.AbstractButtonDriver.requireSelected(AbstractButtonDriver.java:127)
at org.fest.swing.fixture.JRadioButtonFixture.requireSelected(JRadioButtonFixture.java:288)
```

Comment: Need...more...context...

Comment: From the stack trace, we can see nothing interesting except the fact that your radio button is indeed NOT selected (selected = false), hence it is perfectly normal that requireSelected() fails on it! It might be interesting if you also showed us your getFixture() method.

Comment: `getFixture()` is just `new JRadioButtonFixture(dialogFixture.robot, "dialog7button12");`

Comment: You do not modify your JComponents directly (not via FEST) on the JUnit Thread, do you? Also FEST takes a screenshot when a Test fails, maybe you see something there...

Answer (score 1):

I was recently testing with Abbot, FEST precursor, and some failures occurred the same way of yours. In my case, adding a Thread.sleep(300) between the simulation `radio.check()` and the verifier `radio.requireSelected()` solved the issue.

Give it a try.

Comment: Instead of Thread.sleep() try getRobot().waitForIdle(), it's a FEST utility method that will wait for the AWT event queue to empty before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify how the test fails and maybe show the setUp() method. It could be basically anything with the information you've given.